# convert a txt file as data frame in python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a text file with some data. I need to split my text file into data frame. This is my text file:

```
    2012/02/03 18:55:54 SampleClass1 verb detail for id 19471668
    verb detail for id 185289
    verb detail for id 185289
    verb detail for id 1852849
    2012/03/03 18:55:54 SampleClass8 detail for id 2181536
    2012/04/03 18:55:54 SampleClass1 verb detail for id 1765383670
    2012/05/03 18:55:54 SampleClass9 verb detail for id 1666944491
    2012/06/03 18:55:54 SampleClass8 detail for id 799914029 verb detail for id 185229
```

I want to split a date and time separately and also some string then I need to convert it into a data frame.

My expected output:

```
date       time     desc
2012/02/03 18:55:54 SampleClass9 verb detail for id 1947166588
                    verb  detail for id 185289
                    verb detail for id 185289
                    verb detail for id 1852849

2012/03/03 18:55:54 SampleClass8 detail for id 218851536
                    verb detail for id 1852829
                    verb detail for id 185289
                    verb detail for id 1852849
2012/04/03 18:55:54 SampleClass1 verb detail for id 1765383670
                    verb detail for id 1852829
                    verb detail for id 1852829
                    verb detail for id 1852849
2012/05/03 18:55:54 SampleClass9 verb detail for id 1666944491
                    verb detail for id 1852829
                     verb detail for id 1852829
                     verb detail for id 18528429
2012/06/03 18:55:54 SampleClass8 detail for id 799914029 verb detail for id 1852844029
                    verb detail for id 1852829
                    verb detail for id 1852829
                    verb detail for id 18528429
```

Comment: How big is your text file? How many rows do you have?

Comment: it  have more than 500 rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the data you have put, the below code does the job.

```
import csv
import pandas as pd
    
file = "/path/to/file/"
# Open CSV file
with open(file, "r", newline="") as fp:
    # Read the text file and use a space delimiter
    reader = csv.reader(fp, delimiter=" ")
    rows = []
    # loop through the rows
    for row in reader:
        # if empty row then continue
        if not row:
            continue
        #if the first character of the row is a number join the columns after
        # column 2, as columns one and two are already separated
        elif row[0][0].isdigit():
            rows.append(row[:2]+ [' '.join(row[2:])])
        # else add two columns and then join the columns
        else:
            rows.append(['','']+ [' '.join(row)])
        df = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=['date','time','desc'])
```

Comment: Thank you, it works but the problem is that the 'verb' ,'detail' are comes under the date and time  column , i want that the entire line has  to come under the desc column

Comment: I updated the answer. Please check and let me know if it is not clear to you

Comment: i tried it , it throws error IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: It works perfectly with the data you add in the question. I have just tried it. Can you elaborate more about the error?
One thing to check if it is to do with a specific row of the data is to add print(row) inside the for loop

Comment: It is hard to say what is the issue without having the actual data file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229152/discussion-between-ali-sultan-and-shabu-shankar).